# Calling "ImportCatalog" Job step from a script as part of a custom job in SFRA

Tags: job, b2c, salesfront-reference-architecture

I want to call the ImportCatalog pipelet in a custom job that I am writing in SFRA. I came across the job step created for it in SFRA, so I was wondering, if there was a way to call the step through my script in the codebase instead of configuring it on BM.

There's a lot of stuff I need to do in the script for the custom job, so I can't create job steps simply in the BM. Therefore, while configuring the job, I just add a job step to run the script file instead that would call the available system pipelets wherever needed. Any tips or solution would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [job-components](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components) library. It has examples of [how to call Pipelines](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components/blob/bf53730d31f7ac02ece41bf3d4851943dd4f625b/cartridges/bc_job_components/cartridge/scripts/jobsteps/StandardImport.js#L94) and pass in filepaths which would then import/validate a file.

I understand that you don't want to configure the jobs in BM. However, if you did, then you can trigger them in a number of ways:

You can [trigger jobs via OCAPI](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/data/Resources/Jobs.html?cp=0_16_4_27). Which you could potentially do from a script context with a service call.

However, I think you could also likely call the [RunJobNow Pipelet](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/pipeletapi/html/api/pipelet.RunJobNow.html?cp=0_20_3_13_0) using the [Pipeline](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_system_Pipeline.html?cp=0_20_2_28_10) Class and a custom pipeline that calls that Pipelet.

Keep in mind that the Pipelet option could be deprecated at any time. However, it appears that several LINK Cartridges do this exact thing: https://github.com/search?q=org%3ASalesforceCommerceCloud+RunJobNow&type=code

In fact, you could probably use [this pipeline](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/link_acquia/blob/0c0c0681dd043f287b083aedbe4da417dd39e837/cartridges/drupal/cartridge/pipelines/ExecuteJob.xml) directly in your solution. You have to pass it a `JobName` parameter.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any LINK cartridges that call OCAPI to trigger jobs. So probably the Pipeline approach is your best bet at this time. I do think that Salesforce should probably expose a script module that allows the possibility to trigger a job execution.